# When did Mephisto become the branch director?

Tags: blue-exorcist

According to him, Mephisto sided with humans an indefinite amount of time ago, fearing their extinction due to prolonged wars and demon's invasions. We also know that his current alias originated abou 200 years prior to the manga's events. Then, 100 years ago he started the cloning research, in the Japanese branch that he controlled, as stated in chapter 86. That's when the Asylum was founded as well.

Are there any leads in the manga that might hint at a specific time period for when he was appointed the director of the Japanese branch? I assume it must be between 200 and 100 years ago.

Comment: Having read the manga fairly recently, I don't recall any hints or specifics on the time period being mentioned.